# How to caculate biquad filter coefficient?

Tags: c, filter

This is my C code for calculating biquad filter coefficients.
Most of them is correct but not for peak filter, low shelving and high shelving.

Please help see if anything wrong in my codes.

For example, setting for FS=48000, FC=1000, gain=10dB and Q=0.707, the coefficients is below

```
Low Pass                      :  0.0039160769  0.00783215370  0.0039160769 -1.8153178692  0.8309822083
High Pass                     :  0.9115750194 -1.82315003870  0.9115750194 -1.8153178692  0.8309822083
Band Pass Peak Q              : -0.0597477853  0.00000000000 -1.6619073153 -1.8153178692  0.8309822083
Band Pass Constant Q          :  0.0845088884  0.00000000000 -0.0845088884 -1.8153178692  0.8309822083
Notch                         :  0.9154911041 -1.81531786920  0.9154911041 -1.8153178692  0.8309822083
All Pass                      :  0.8309822083 -1.81531786920  1.0000000000 -1.8153178692  0.8309822083
***Peaking EQ                 :  1.1067041159 -1.88503801820  0.7945997715 -1.8850380182  0.9013039470***
***Low Shelving               :  1.0553481579 -1.85152983670  0.8246886730 -1.8612760305  0.8702906966***
***High Shelving              :  2.9964308739 -5.57718515400  2.6077659130 -1.7544257641  0.7814375758***
```

Expected

```
The value for peak = 
a0 = 1.18273168232815 a1 = -1.8153179156742152 a2 = 0.648250540080863 b1 = -1.8153179156742152 b2 = 0.8309822224090129
Low shelving 
a0 = 1.074230188304032 a1 = -1.7984055763195854 a2 = 0.7737109074277086 b1 = -1.8153410827045682 b2 = 0.8310055893467576
High shelving
a0 = 3.0368659226630146 a1 = -5.757548057807517 a2 = 2.7363466417866915 b1 = -1.8153410827045682 b2 = 0.8310055893467576
```

The compared answer is from http://www.earlevel.com/main/2013/10/13/biquad-calculator-v2/

Reference:
http://shepazu.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html

```
void audio_eq_coefficient(double Q, double dB, double FS, double FC, 
        int type, float *coeff) {

    double n0, n1, n2, d1, d2;
    double b0, b1, b2, a0, a1, a2;
        double w0, cosW, sinW, A, alpha, beta;

    // intermediate parameters
    w0 = 2*M_PI*(FC/FS);
        cosW = cos(w0);
        sinW = sin(w0);
    A = pow(10, (dB/40));
    //printf("A = %lf, dB/40 = %lf\n", A, dB/40);
    alpha = sinW/(2*Q);
    beta = pow(A, 0.5)/Q;

    switch (type) {
    case 0: //Low Pass
        b0 = (1 - cosW)/2;
        b1 = 1 - cosW;
        b2 = (1 - cosW)/2;
        a0 = 1 + alpha;
        a1 = -2*cosW;
        a2 = 1 - alpha;
        break;
    case 1: //High Pass
        b0 = (1 + cosW)/2;
        b1 = -(1 + cosW);
        b2 = (1 + cosW)/2;
        a0 = (1 + alpha);
        a1 = -2*cosW;
        a2 = 1 - alpha;
        break;
    case 2: //Band Pass Peak gain Q
        b0 = sinW/2;
        b1 = 0;
        b0 = -sinW/2;
        a0 = 1 + alpha;
        a1 = -2*cosW;
        a2 = 1 - alpha;
        break;
    case 3: //Band Pass constant 0dB gain
        b0 = alpha;
        b1 = 0;
        b2 = -alpha;
        a0 = 1 + alpha;
        a1 = -2*cosW;
        a2 = 1 - alpha;
        break;
    case 4: //Notch Filter
        b0 = 1;
        b1 = -2*cosW;
        b2 = 1;
        a0 = 1 + alpha;
        a1 = -2*cosW;
        a2 = 1 - alpha;
        break;
    case 5: //All pass
        b0 = 1 - alpha;
        b1 = -2*cosW;
        b2 = 1 + alpha;
        a0 = 1 + alpha;
        a1 = -2*cosW;
        a2 = 1 - alpha;
        break;
    case 6: // Peaking EQ Filter
        b0 = 1 + (alpha*A);
        b1 = -2*cosW;
        b2 = 1 - (alpha*A);
        a0 = 1 + (alpha/A);
        a1 = -2*cosW;
        a2 = 1 - (alpha/A);
        break;
    case 7: //Low Shelving Filter
        b0 = A*((A + 1) - ((A -1)*cosW) + beta*sinW);
        b1 = 2*A*((A - 1) - ((A + 1)*cosW));
        b2 = A*((A + 1) - (A - 1)*cosW - beta*sinW);
        a0 = ((A + 1) + (A - 1)*cosW + beta*sinW);
        a1 = -2*((A - 1) + (A + 1)*cosW);
        a2 = ((A + 1) + (A - 1)*cosW - (beta*sinW));
        break;
    case 8: //High Shelving Filter
        b0 = A*((A + 1) + (A - 1)*cosW + beta*sinW);
        b1 = -2*A*((A - 1) + (A + 1)*cosW);
        b2 = A*((A + 1) + (A - 1)*cosW -beta*sinW);
        a0 = ((A + 1) - (A - 1)*cosW + beta*sinW);
        a1 = 2*((A - 1) - (A + 1)*cosW);
        a2 = ((A + 1) - (A - 1)*cosW - beta*sinW);
        break;
    default:
        break;  

    };

    n0 = b0/a0;
    n1 = b1/a0;
    n2 = b2/a0;
    d1 = a1/a0;
    d2 = a2/a0;
    //printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", n0, n1, n2, d1, d2);
    coeff[0] = (float)n0;
    coeff[1] = (float)n1;
    coeff[2] = (float)n2;
    coeff[3] = (float)d1;
    coeff[4] = (float)d2;

}

static char str_filter[9][30] = {"Low Pass", "High Pass", "Band Pass Peak Q", "Band Pass Constant Q",
                "Notch", "All Pass", "Peaking EQ", "Low Shelving", "High Shelving"};


int main(){
    float coeff[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        audio_eq_coefficient(0.707, 10, 48000, 1000, i, coeff);
        printf("%-30s: %13.10f %13.10f0 %13.10f %13.10f %13.10f\n",
                str_filter[i], coeff[0], coeff[1], coeff[2],
                coeff[3], coeff[4]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To add clarity ,add to this post the expected values for "Peaking EQ, Low Shelving and High Shelving".

Comment: Why is `/Low Shelving Filter
        b0 = A*((A + 1) - ((A -1)*cosW) + beta*sinW);` not coded like the formula in [ref](http://shepazu.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html)?

Comment: The value for 
peak = a0 = 1.18273168232815
a1 = -1.8153179156742152
a2 = 0.648250540080863
b1 = -1.8153179156742152
b2 = 0.8309822224090129

Low shelving
a0 = 1.074230188304032
a1 = -1.7984055763195854
a2 = 0.7737109074277086
b1 = -1.8153410827045682
b2 = 0.8310055893467576

High shelving
a0 = 3.0368659226630146
a1 = -5.757548057807517
a2 = 2.7363466417866915
b1 = -1.8153410827045682
b2 = 0.8310055893467576

Comment: α=sin(ω0)/2⋅Q, so 2*√A*α =  (beta = pow(A, 0.5)/Q) * sin(ω0)

Answer (score 1):

Code does not fully implement the referenced [Cookbook formulae for audio equalizer biquad filter coefficients](http://shepazu.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html) equation #4.

There are 3 cases and code only codes case Q `alpha = sinW/(2*Q);`.  The missing code corresponds to the filters OP is having trouble: peak (case: BW) and shelving (case: S).

```
  case: Q
  α=sin(ω0)/(2⋅Q)
  case: BW
  α=sin(ω0)⋅sinh(ln(2)/2⋅BW⋅ω0/sin(ω0))
  case: S
  α=sin(ω0)/22⋅√((A+1/A)⋅(1/S−1)+2)
```

---

Note: With no stated reason to use `float` and coding these equations already do all of the calculations with at least `double` math, recommend to re-code to use only `double`.  `float *coeff` --> `double *coeff`.

Comment: Yes, I should implement Q, BW and S. But I have problems for calculating correct coefficient for peak, low shelving and high shelving.
Thanks

Comment: @SamChen "have problems for calculating correct coefficient for peak, low shelving and high shelving" --> that is because the  `α` is different in peak, low shelving and high shelving.  Does not  the new  `α` result in the expected coefficients?

Comment: I follows this algorithm http://www.earlevel.com/scripts/widgets/20131013/biquads2.js to get the correct coefficient.
It works !
Thanks.